# How to draw a higher-genus surface

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

**NB**: By *higher-genus surface*, I mean a closed orientable surface of genus at least 2.

This question has come up before on math.SE, and even MathOverflow, but most posters suggested using either Blender or Inkscape.  However, I would like to draw these higher-genus surfaces in Mathematica, because I am trying to create a Manipulate which takes as input a word in the fundamental group of such a surface, and outputs the corresponding geodesic, drawn on the surface.

So, for example, let's say I am trying to draw a genus 2 surface.  What I am doing now is the following:

```
torus = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[s]) Cos[t], (2 + Cos[s]) Sin[t], 
Sin[s]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, x < 2]];
antitorus = 
Graphics3D[
Translate[
GeometricTransformation[torus[[1]], 
ReflectionTransform[{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}]], {1, 0, 0}], 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
bound = ParametricPlot3D[{{t, (2 + Cos[s]) Sqrt[
  1 - 4/((2 + Cos[s])^2)], 
Sin[s]}, {t, -(2 + Cos[s]) Sqrt[1 - 4/((2 + Cos[s])^2)], 
Sin[s]}}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 2, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.7]}, 
Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100];
Show[antitorus,torus,bound,Lighting->"Neutral"]
```

This gives me this (not-so-bad!) picture:

[image]

I am wondering what other methods there are for creating these surfaces, perhaps with a smoother finished product than the one I currently have.

And of course, ideally, I would eventually draw the two "building blocks" of all such surfaces, the once- and twice-punctured tori.  Then I could dynamically build these surfaces on the fly...

Comment: Presumably, your surface must be *connected,* too--otherwise there are some obvious and simple solutions :-).

Comment: Does Stan Wagon's one-liner double torus look like the sort of thing you are looking for? `ContourPlot3D[(x^4 - x^2 + y^2)^2 + 9 z^2 == .04, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -.4, .4}, PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ContourStyle -> Yellow]`

Comment: Stan Wagon's 2 double torus's can be found at http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/17/the-mathematica-one-liner-competition/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you dig through [**Eric Weisstein notebook**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleTorus.html) you can find this well parametrized version. I changed parameters and styles a bit to get closer to your shape.

```
With[{R = 1.2, r = 1/2, a = Sqrt[2]}, 
 ContourPlot3D[-a^2 + ((-r^2 + R^2)^2 - 
       2 (r^2 + R^2) ((-r - R + x)^2 + y^2) + 
       2 (-r^2 + R^2) z^2 + ((-r - R + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2) ((-r^2 + 
         R^2)^2 - 2 (r^2 + R^2) ((r + R + x)^2 + y^2) + 
       2 (-r^2 + R^2) z^2 + ((r + R + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2) == 
   0, {x, -2 (r + R), 2 (r + R)}, {y, -(r + R), (r + R)}, {z, -r - a, 
   r + a}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 35, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

OK digging through [**Eric Weisstein another notebook**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TripleTorus.html) I figured a "tentative" generalization, - at least it works with n=3 or n=4. The rest needs more time (also [**look here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152256)):

```
torusImplicit[{x_, y_, z_}, R_, r_] = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 - 
   2 (R^2 + r^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 2 (R^2 - r^2) z^2 + (R^2 - r^2)^2;

build[n_] := 
  Module[{f, cp, polys, cartPolys, cartPolys1},(*implicit polynomial*)
   f = Product[
      torusImplicit[{x - 1.5 Cos[i 2 Pi/n], y - 1.5 Sin[i 2 Pi/n], z},
        1, 1/4], {i, 0, n - 1}] - 10;
   cp = ContourPlot3D[
     Evaluate[f == 0], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, 
     BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 35, 
     MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
     ContourStyle -> 
      Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]], 
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]];

build[3]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is pretty!

Comment: How hard would it be to generalize to higher genus?

Comment: @SteveD thx :P well i added some stuff about higher order

Comment: Oh wow, the answers on this thread are incredible!

Comment: As an alternative, if you replace `f` with `f = Product[torusImplicit[{x - 2.35 i, y, z}, 1, 1/4], {i, 0, n - 1}] - 10`, you get the holes in a line.

Answer (score 12):

Quick and dirty: look at the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of a union of circles.

```
circle[x_, n_: 32] := {x + Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n];
Graphics3D[Tube[circle[#, 72], .5] & /@ Range[-3, 3, 2], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Space them approximately two units apart (using `x`) and keep their radii less than $1/2$.

---

For smooth surfaces--albeit at a price--we may subvert `RegionPlot3D` to do our work.  It's a similar idea, only now we apply a 3D buffer to a circular skeleton rather than using tubular neighborhoods of fixed radius:

```
d[{x_, y_, z_}, x0_: 0] := Block[{u, v}, {u, v} = {x0, 0} + Normalize[{x - x0, y}]; 
  Norm[{u, v, 0} - {x, y, z}]^2];
RegionPlot3D[Min[d[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ Range[-2, 2, 2]] <= 1/2, {x, -4,4}, {y, -2,2}, {z, -2,2}, 
  BoxRatios -> {4, 2, 2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Genus 3]

The argument `x0` to `d` shifts the skeleton's center to `x0` along the x-axis.  Taking a contour of the shortest distance to a collection of circular skeletons does the job.

Comment: Set `n` to $4$ in `circle[#, 4]` to get an interesting version.

Comment: This is a quick, nice way to do it.  But the "joins" aren't very smooth. :)

Comment: I'll get you smoother joins, Steve--just a minute.

Comment: Oh, I wish I could upvote again for the smooth version!

Comment: Actually, if you do some algebraic manipulation of the smooth version, you will obtain a solution almost identical (if not identical) to that of Vitaliy Kaurov.  That shows how solutions like his can readily be derived and why they do generalize--and how to generalize them.  You can also have some fun here by modifying my function `d` to draw circles in arbitrary locations with arbitrary orientations: with that you can draw pictures to your heart's content, spacing and sizing the holes as you wish, twisting the figure, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

By using the **Erdős lemniscate of order n**:

```
erdos[z_, n_] := Abs[z^n - 1]^2 - 1;
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
  erdos[x + I y, 3]^2 + (16*Abs[x + I y]^4 + 1)*(z^2 - 0.12^2);
ContourPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 ContourStyle -> {StippleShading[0.5], White}, Lighting -> "Accent", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I upvoted, but I also do not recall Erdős having ever studied lemniscates. Would you happen to have a reference for how or where these got named after him?

Comment: I think the original reference is https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02790232, but there is also a section on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_lemniscate

Comment: @Hausdorff and cvgmt, these should keep me busy for a bit. Thank you! (edit: It looks like this generalizes the [sinusoidal spirals](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/spiralesinusoidale/spiralesinusoidale.shtml).)

Comment: https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dwebgl/genusthree.asy

Answer (score 5):

The following pokes `n` holes in flattish blob:

```
genus[n_] := Module[{pts, fn},
  pts = If[n == 1, {0, 0}, 
    Table[2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 2 \[Pi]/n, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n}]];
  fn = 10 z^2 + 
    Total[Join[#/n, (2 + 2/n)/#] &[#.# &[{x, y} - #] & /@ pts]]; 
  ContourPlot3D[fn == 18, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Yellow, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
  ]
```

[image: Array of genus 2,..,7 surfaces]

Note:
The expression `fn` is $10\,z^2$ plus the sum over all points `pts` of $k\,d^2 + l/d^2$, where $d$ is the distance to the point (dropping $z$ coordinates) and $k$, $l$ are coefficients depending on the number of holes $n$.  The upshot is that the function goes to infinity at the vertical lines through the points and as $(x,y,z)$ moves away from the points.

```
With[{n = 1}, 
 10 z^2 + Total[Join[#/n, (2 + 2/n)/#] &[#.# &[{x, y} - #] & /@ {{a, b}}]]]

(* -> (-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 + 4/((-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2) + 10 z^2 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a double torus by [**Stan Wagon**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2902/stan-wagon) from the [2010 one-liner competition](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/17/the-mathematica-one-liner-competition/)

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^4 - x^2 + y^2)^2 + 9 z^2 == 0.04,
              {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.4, 0.4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `Boxed`, `Axes`, and `Mesh` set to `False` and the equation = `0.03`:

[image: meshless double torus]

Comment: I find this slightly *ugly*; it is not the usual, voluptuous double-torus I know and love. :)

Comment: I know what you mean. It will look slightly better without the mesh, but the shape is more like a bee-stung 8.

Answer (score 3):

Wagon's formulation of the double torus, as featured in David's answer, is based on the [Gerono lemniscate](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EightCurve.html). I find that using [Booth's lemniscate](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/booth/booth.shtml) (of which [Bernoulli](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html)'s is a special case) instead, with its adjustable parameters, to be more flexible. Here are two examples:

```
With[{a = 5, b = 4, c = 5, f = 3/4}, 
     ContourPlot3D[((x^2 + y^2)^2 - a x^2 + b y^2)^2 + c z^2 == f,
                   {x, -5/2, 5/2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, 
                   BoxRatios -> Automatic]]
```

[image: double torus based on Booth lemniscate]

```
With[{a = 3, b = 3, c = 10, f = 1/2}, 
     ContourPlot3D[((x^2 + y^2)^2 - a x^2 + b y^2)^2 + c z^2 == f,
                   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2},
                   BoxRatios -> Automatic]]
```

[image: one more double torus]

Of course, one can put all this in a `Manipulate[]` to explore the effects of changing the parameters, but I'll leave that up to the sufficiently interested reader.

Similar things can be done with e.g. [rose curves](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rose.html) or [sinusoidal spirals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinusoidalSpiral.html) if higher genus surfaces are desired.