# How to draw a box with holes using Mathematica

Tags: graphics3d

[image]

How to draw these two(especially the second one) graphs using Mathematica?
The curve is not important.The point is how to dig some holes in a cube.
BTW, These two shapes are Homotopy.

Comment: Providing functions for the figures or some example of what you have tried would be helpful.  Start by looking at the documentation for `ParametricPlot3D`

Comment: Probable using RegionPlot3D

Comment: For the first surface, see [How to draw a higher genus surface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-draw-a-higher-genus-surface)

Comment: Are these really homotopic? Homeomorphic, I can see - but homotopic requires a deformation that disentangles those tubes. Given an explicit homotopy, we should be able to animate the deformation.

Answer (score 11):

```
r = 1/40;
sides = ParametricPlot3D[{
    {0, u, v}, {1, u, v}, {u, 1, v}, {u,0,v}
    }, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 7, 
   PlotStyle -> {
     Directive[Purple, Opacity[0.6]],
     Directive[Purple, Opacity[0.6]],
     Directive[Purple, Opacity[0.6]],
     Directive[Purple, Opacity[0.2]]
   },
   MeshStyle -> {
     Directive[Opacity[0.2]],
     Directive[Opacity[0.2]],
     Directive[Opacity[0.2]],
     Directive[Opacity[0.05]]
   },
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
topBot = ParametricPlot3D[{
    {u, v, 1}, {u, v, 0}
    }, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 7, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, Opacity[.4]],
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 55,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{u, v},
     (u - 1/5)^2 + (v - 1/2)^2 > r^2 &&
      (u - 1/2)^2 + (v - 1/2)^2 > r^2 &&
      (u - 4/5)^2 + (v - 1/2)^2 > r^2]];
p[t_] = {0.1 (Cos[4 Pi*t] - 2 Cos[2 Pi*t] + 1) + 1/5,
   0.2 (Sin[4 Pi*t] - Sin[2 Pi*t]) + 1/2,
   ((2.5 (t - 1/2)) - (2.5 (t - 1/2))^3 + 45/64) 32/45};
tubes = ParametricPlot3D[{p[t], {1/2, 1/2, t}, {4/5, 1/2, t}},
    {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White,10], Purple, Opacity[.6]]
    ] /. Line[pts_] :> {CapForm[None], Tube[pts, r]};
join = ParametricPlot3D[{
    {1/5, 1/2, 0} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0},
    {1/2, 1/2, 0} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0},
    {4/5, 1/2, 0} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0},
    {1/5, 1/2, 1} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0},
    {1/2, 1/2, 1} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0},
    {4/5, 1/2, 1} + r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}
    }, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Purple, Opacity[0.2]]
   ];
Show[{sides, topBot, tubes, join},
 ViewPoint -> {1.25833, -2.927, 1.1384}]
```

[image]

Comment: where can I find the techniques like that  `/. Line[pts_] :> {` , which is very cool because it is followed after the plot function and Line is not explicitly appear in the plot function. I just want to know more of these cool.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I could feel myself drilling the holes in the sides, bending the pipes, joining the ends to these sides then gluing the remaining 4 sides...very nice + 1 :)

Comment: @peter You can learn a lot about this type of programming in the documentation's section on [the structure of graphics](http://goo.gl/mpXHT6). In particular, you'll learn that plotting command (like `ParametricPlot3D`) produce graphics primitives (like `Line`). So, if you execute something like `InputForm[ParametricPlot3D[{t,t,t}, {t,0,1}]`, you'll see that a `Line` has been produced. The `/.Line[pts_] :>` business simply replaces it with a `Tube`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thank you very much.`p[t_] = {0.1 (Cos[4 Pi*t] - 2 Cos[2 Pi*t] + 1) + 1/5,
   0.2 (Sin[4 Pi*t] - Sin[2 Pi*t]) + 1/2,
   ((2.5 (t - 1/2)) - (2.5 (t - 1/2))^3 + 45/64) 32/45};`can you tell me a little about how you came up with this function?is there some secret of making this...

Comment: @peter Honestly, I just looked at it. I figured the $z$ coordinate had to start way up high, go pretty low, then pretty high, then way down low - so I came up with $t-t^3$ over some interval. I then scaled and shifted that so that it fit. I did similar things with the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Too much looking at functions over the years, I guess.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As MichaelE2's comment  there are a number of ways of generating the left figure.

Using [whubers `circle` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20914/1997).:

```
circle[x_, n_: 32] := {x + Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ 
   Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n];

Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Tube[circle[#] & /@ Range[-2, 2, 2], 0.4]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

gives:

[image]

Mark McClure's construction of a boxes six sides, putting tubes inside and holes in parallel sides and joining the tube ends to the   side holes gets my vote. Just looking inside the 'purple box' by removing two sides shows the internal plumbing:

[image]

I post the following (which "drills" holes in the cubic region), not as efficient but as a way, using Mark McClure's parametric curve. If the extrusion is too big the tube intersects itself and it takes much longer.

```
p[t_] = {0.1 (Cos[4 Pi*t] - 2 Cos[2 Pi*t] + 1) + 1/5, 
   0.2 (Sin[4 Pi*t] - Sin[2 Pi*t]) + 
    1/2, ((2.5 (t - 1/2)) - (2.5 (t - 1/2))^3 + 45/64) 32/45};
pp = ParametricPlot3D[p[t], {t, 0, 1}];
reg = First@Cases[pp, Line[x__], Infinity];
rf = RegionDistance[reg]
h2 = Line[Table[{1/2, 1/2, j}, {j, 0, 1, 0.1}]];
rf2 = RegionDistance[h2];
h3 = Line[Table[{3/4, 1/2, j}, {j, 0, 1, 0.1}]];
rf3 = RegionDistance[h3];
RegionPlot3D[
 rf[{x, y, z}] > 0.02 && rf2[{x, y, z}] > 0.02 && 
  rf3[{x, y, z}] > 0.02, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

gives this:

[image]

This takes sometime on my machine...