# Getting errors when I try to evaluate code taken from Trott's Mathematica Guidebook for Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, compatibility, broken-code

I would like to learn how to make high quality images in *Mathematica*.  In my pursuit, I have come across Michael Trott's *Mathematica Guidebook for Graphics*.  I have been trying some of the examples, but I find that many of them don't work.  For example, I would like for the following code to work:

```
torus[phi1_, phi2_, r1_, r2_] = 
  {r1 + r2, 0, 0} + 
  {r1 Cos[phi1] + r2 Cos[phi1] Cos[phi2], 
   r1 Sin[phi1] + r2 Sin[phi1] Cos[phi2], 
   r2 Sin[phi2]};

parts = 
  {{torus[phi1, phi2, 3, 1], {{phi1, 0, Pi/2}, {phi2, 0, Pi}}, 
      {pphi1 + 1, pphi2 + 1}}, 
   {torus[phi1, phi2, 3, 1], {{phi1, Pi/2, Pi}, {phi2, Pi/2, Pi}}, 
      {pphi1, pphi2/2 + 1}}, 
   {x # {0, 1, 1} + (1 - x) # & [torus[Pi/2, phi2, 3, 1]], 
      {{x, 0, 1}, {phi2, 0, Pi/2}}, {pphi1, pphi2/2 + 1}}, 
   {x  # {0, 1, 1} + (1 - x) # & [torus[phi1, Pi/2, 3, 1]], 
      {{phi1, Pi/2, Pi}, {x, 0, 1}}, {pphi1, pphi2}}};

pphi1 = 24; pphi2 = 24;
polys = 
  Cases[
    ParametricPlot3D[#1, Evaluate[Sequence @@ #2], 
      PlotPoints -> #3, 
      DisplayFunction -> Identity],
    _Polygon, Infinity] & @@@ parts;

makeSeams[{f_, {{x_, x1_, x2_}, {y_, y1_, y2_}}, {ppx_, ppy_}}] := 
  Line /@ {
    Table[f /. x -> x1, {y, y1, y2, (y2 - y1)/(ppy - 1)}], 
    Table[f /. x -> x2, {y, y1, y2, (y2 - y1)/(ppy - 1)}], 
    Table[f /. y -> y1, {x, x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/(ppx - 1)}], 
    Table[f /. y -> y2, {x, x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/(ppx - 1)}]} // N

seams = makeSeams /@ parts;

Show[
  Graphics3D[{
    EdgeForm[], Thickness[0.001], 
    {SurfaceColor[Hue[Random[]], Hue[Random[]], 2.5], #} & /@ polys, 
    seams}]]
```

However, I keep getting an error saying that the array produced has the wrong dimensions for a coordinate list.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-draw-a-higher-genus-surface

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap `ParametricPlot3D` with `Normal`. The problem is that *Mathematica* starting from version 6 introduces more advanced data type `GraphicsComplex`. `Normal` converts to good old `Graphics3D`.

Michael Trott's *"Mathematica Guidebook for Graphics"* was written for version 5.

```
polys = Cases[
 Normal[
  ParametricPlot3D[#1, Evaluate[Sequence @@ #2], PlotPoints -> #3,
    DisplayFunction -> Identity]], _Polygon, Infinity] & @@@ parts;
```

Comment: Your solution works great, thank you.  Do you have any recommendations for learning how to update his code?

Comment: New Mathematica versions have much more visualization possibilities, therefore many of Trotts attempts  now can be realized with far less of efforts. Sure the book code can be adopted with afew of correcting commands and list brackets. However, I doubt if one to one code update have a sense in the light of of new and much more powerful possibilities. I think the entire approach should be reconsidered.