# Integral of (Elementary) Volume Form over Orientable Surface of Genus 2?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

Per [this post on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351012/trigonometric-parametrization-of-a-genus-g-surface), I am told it is impossible to find an elementary formula for a coordinate patch covering of the orientable surface of genus 2 (or higher genus) (or the non-orientable ones?). Per [this post on mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-draw-a-higher-genus-surface), there appear to be elementary formulas for the above-mentioned surfaces.

Is it possible to 1) write elementary formula coordinate patches for the above-mentioned orientable surfaces and elementary formulas for their volume 2-forms and integrate their volume forms over them, as in the Mathematics notebooks using the [DifferentialForms.m](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/482/) package [here](http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/CircleLIForm.nb) and [here](http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/TorusLIForm.nb)? I would like to have Mathematica scripts for all of these phenomena (of course, there are infinitely many such surfaces, but there should be a pattern?). Thanks in advance.